# Install perl-LWP-Protocol-https in RHEL - 4.7

Tags: linux, api, perl, unix

my server runs on Red Hat Enterprise Linux - 4.7 . For some reason I cannot go ahead and upgrade my server. I wanted to install "perl-LWP-Protocol-https" module in it. Could someone help me, how to  achieve it ?

Comment: The reason why people use RHEL (instead of, say, Centos) is for the support. RHEL 4.x has been completely unsupported for over three years. Please don't use in. In particular, don't use in on a server that is connected to the internet.

Comment: You were using OEL 6.10 [in your last question about this module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61187013/install-perl-lwp-protocol-https)...

Comment: Have you tried `perl -MCPAN -e install LWP::Protocol::https`? Usage of [retired](https://endoflife.software/operating-systems/linux/red-hat-enterprise-linux-rhel) version of [RHEL](https://access.redhat.com/articles/3078) is a bad idea -- no updates, and no security updates for known vulnerabilities. Why not to use [CentOS](https://www.centos.org/) or [Fedora](https://getfedora.org/) if you would like to stay on RPM package management system?

Comment: To upgrade RHEL server you need a subscription which cost money. Only way around it to use updates from [Fedora](https://getfedora.org/). But with so outdated version of RHEL installation of [Fedora](https://getfedora.org/) make more sense than trying to fix something so old and unsupported any more  (End of life: February 29, 2012 / End of extended life: March 31, 2017).